# Ansible read variables from bash

Tags: bash, variables, cmd, ansible

I created 2 playbooks:

1. deploy VM(centos8) into ESX
2. join VM to AD

Inside of them are plenty variables which are useful only for one specific VM (beside info about ESX)

```
---
- name: create vm from template on ESX
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: clone the template
    vmware_guest:
      hostname:  "IP.."
      username: "user"
      password: "password"
      validate_certs: false
      name: ll-ansible
      template: ll
      datacenter: "LAB KE"
      folder: "OIR"
      resource_pool: "pool"
      cluster: "PROD cluster"
      networks:
        - name: IS-VLAN1102
          device_type: vmxnet3
          vlan: IS-VLAN1102
          ip: ip.ip.ip.ip
          netmask: 255.255.255.0
          gateway: gw.gw.gw.gw
      customization:
          hostname: ll-ansible
          timezone: timezone
          domain: domain
          dns_servers:
            - ip.ip.ip.ip
            - ip.ip.ip.ip
      disk:
        - size: 60gb
          type: default
          datastore: Dell-OIR
        - size: 10gb
          type: default
          datastore: Dell-OIR
      hardware:
        memory_mb: 4096
        num_cpus: 4
        num_cpu_cores_per_socket: 2
        boot-firmware: efi

      state: poweredon
      wait_for_ip_address: yes
    register: vm
  - debug: msg "{{ vm }}"
```

My question is:

Is there a way to make a script which will read all necessary variables for deploying `VM` from command line and fill fields in playbook and then run playbook.

Or if is it possible make it only within `ansible` possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to send variables to playbook.

Let's start from these 3 most popular options:

- `env` vars
- `ansible-playbook` CLI arguments
- var files

See also all 22 options: [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

## Option 1: use `lookup('env')` in the playbook

Just use `"{{ lookup('env', 'ENV_VAR_NAME')}}"`

E.g., for your case:

```yaml
---
- name: create vm from template on ESX
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: clone the template
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: "{{ lookup('env', 'IP_ADDRESS')}}"
```

## Option 2: pass var through `CLI` args

You may pass Env var value using `--extra-vars` `CLI` argument

For your case:

playbook.yml

```yaml
...
  - name: clone the template
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: "{{ ip_address }}"
      user: "{{ user }}"
```

usage:

```
 ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars="user={{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}, ip_address='10.10.10.10'"
```

## Option 3: use `vars_files` in the playbook

For your case:

playbook.yml:

```yaml
---
- name: create vm from template on ESX
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - "vars/vars.yml"

  tasks:

  - name: clone the template
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
```

vars/vars.yml:

```
---
hostname: "host.example.com"
```

## Let's combine them all:

Suppose you have two different environments:

- `staging` for staging environment
- `prod` for productive environment

Then we create two different `vars` files:

vars/staging.yml

```
---
hostname: "staging.domain.com"
```

vars/prod.yml

```
---
hostname: "prod.domain.com"
```

playbook.yml:

```yaml
---
- name: create vm from template on ESX
 y6uu hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - "vars/{{ env }}.yml"

  tasks:

  - name: clone the template
    vmware_guest:
      hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
```

### Usage

- run playbook with `staging` vars:
   `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars=staging`
- run playbook with `prod` vars:
   `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars=prod`

Comment: hi Yasen,   thanks a lot , its clear now, so  i just _have to_  use another yml file with variables,,, and what i want  is that i can edit these yml variable  via script ,,you know,   let say new VM  is requested, i execute script with will change variables in var.yml file and then run deploy playbook,,, so i do not touch var.yml file at all (only if some new variable appeared) ....then i can run:                                                                  e.g.     #  ./edit_prod.sh (which change variables in prod_var.yml)  && deploy.yml   ,,is this approach correct in your opinion?   thx

Comment: Consider `Option 2` instead of your approach: it should a bit simpler.